# JComboBox Warning preventing opening the design page in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jcombobox

OK i am using eclipse and its GUI editor and i have a string like this:

```
public static String[] blah = {"Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah"};
```

and a JComboBox like this:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(blah);
    comboBox.setBounds(10, 56, 312, 37);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
```

The combobox uses the string above to get its data but when i enter in "blah" to the combobox it has this error...

```
Type safety: The constructor JComboBox(Object[]) belongs to the raw type JComboBox.    References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized
```

it works if i run it because it is only a warning but it is annoying because it wont let me enter design mode unless i make it a comment. design mode gives this error...

```
INVALID SOURCE. No Constructor Binding. ---  new JComboBox(locations) is not valid source for component creation, it references not existing constructor.
```

so i would like to know if there is any other way to overcome this issue

Comment: You can use annotations to get around this. By the way, don't use setBounds(...). Use layout managers. Also, are you sure that you want to use a GUI editor?

Comment: I have to use absolute layout for this particular program and yes a GUI editor is a must for this particular project, what do you mean by annotations

Comment: *"I have to use absolute layout for this particular program"* **Why?** *"and yes a GUI editor is a must for this particular project,"* **Why?**  IMWTK.

Comment: `it references not existing constructor.` Given that is not correct English, I suspect you did not copy/paste the text.  Is it possible to copy the text direct from the Eclipse design mode warning?

Comment: "new JComboBox(locations) is not valid source for component creation, it references not existing constructor." is exactly what it says and "I have to use absolute layout for this particular program" Why? "and yes a GUI editor is a must for this particular project," Why? im not going to answer this frankly because it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: "im not going to answer this frankly because it has nothing to do with the question and it is none of your business". If you're trying to motivate us to help you further, consider a different tack. Best of luck with this and future projects.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - i didn't mean it in a mean way i just didn't really want to answer it because it didn't have anything to do with the question, If you must know i am using the absolute layout because i have heaps of objects that need to be aligned and i am using a GUI editor because i am new to java GUI's an needed a easy place to start (since i came from vb .net). Thank-you for you comment though i realize now that i should not have said that

Comment: @Lucas_F98: Thank  you for the clarification of what you meant. You can read up more on annotations here: [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html). I believe that the annotation of interest would be the @SuppressWarnings annotation, perhaps this would work: `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`. And yes, while my other questions were not directly related to your original question, they have indirect bearing, in particular the use of a GUI editor which is a double edged sword that can potentially help and hurt you. ...

Comment: These utilities shield you from the underpinnings of the Swing library, and yes this can possibly makes it easier to create a simple GUI, but the shielding can inhibit your understanding of what you're doing which can slow down your speed of learning Swing, and make it easier to make basic mistakes. The code-generation utilities also force you into their rigid paradigm which can make it more difficult to extend your application, especially if you want to make anything more than the most basic of GUI's or modify their code. ...

Comment: Shoot, who knows if your utility will even allow you to add the annotation where you need to without invalidating its gui setup files. Luck. /Pete (aka Fubarable).

Comment: Lucas_F98 we're with you, forget this Hovercraft guy. The problem is an issue with Windowbuilder Pro, you really have to compile everything with Java6 and use Java6, because Java7 added this new requirement for JComboBoxes to have types, which WindowBuilder dislikes. Thanks to Michael Wolf for pointing this out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seams to be that WindowBuilder can't handle the generics version of `JComboBox<E>` whitch is new in jre7.

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the **jre6** under **Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs** and ensuring that the project uses the execution Environment **'JavaSE-1.6'** under **Project -> properties -> Java Compiler**.

So if you don't need java 7 you can easily fix it, else you have to wait for Windowbuilder to support the generics version.

Answer (score 10):

```
// comboBoxTraceModeSelection = new JComboBox<TraceMode>(TraceMode.values());
   comboBoxTraceModeSelection = new JComboBox<TraceMode>();
   comboBoxTraceModeSelection.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<TraceMode>
(TraceMode.values()));
```

This is a workaround for when using enum in a JComboBox (with WindowBuilder on Eclipse 3.7.2 for java 6). Yes, it does seem to be related to Java generics for objects that are a bit out of the ordinary (enum, String, etc). TraceMode is a custom enum. The commented-out line causes the same error as that of the original poster. This is a WindowBuilder issue, not an Eclipse or Java issue.

Answer (score 7):

I think OP already got an useful answer since 3 years are gone :D however, hope you'll find this useful :

Actually I don't know why we get this error but u can easily get rid of it by separing the ComboBoxModel creation and the JComboBox creation.

Defining first the model (e.g. using DefaultComboBoxModel), adding the needed elements and then passing the above model to JComboBox constructor, does not result in this error and works fine.

E.g.

```
public static String[] blah = {"Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah"};

DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(blah);

JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(comboModel);`
```

Quite concise and readable, I think :)

Comment: Thanks, it solve my problem. I had the problem with JComboBox<String> so it nor related to generics, nor to old java.

Comment: I like this particular fix.  It's a great workaround even with WB 1.9.7.2021xxx and JDK 12