# Java swing JComboBox can't be parametrized

Tags: java, swing, generics, jcombobox, java-7

Eclipse IDE showing error on Jcombobox which says that JcomboBox can't be parametarized
eg :something like line showing below

```
private final JComboBox<LaborHelper> labourname = new JComboBox<LaborHelper>();
```

here my project execution environment is javaSE1.6

Comment: That's because... `JComboBox` can't be parametrized...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [java 1.6 documentation for JComboxBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html), the class `JComboxBox` is not a generic class for Java 1.6.

It takes an array or a vector of **objects** as choices for the users and displays them by calling the toString method of the objects (so you have to override it if you want to customize the labels).

To access the value that the user selected, you will have to cast the selected item as follows:
`(LaborHelper)labourname.field.getSelectedItem()`

However, [this should work with java 1.7+](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) as `JComboxBox` became a generic class.

Comment: here is my java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode) but still same error

Comment: @chrish It's the version of te compiler that is important. What version do you get when doing `javac.exe -version`?

Comment: i am using eclipse. how can i check weather which version of complier that eclipse using?

Comment: @chrish There should be the jdk settings somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The `JComboBox` did not support the type specification (parametrized) before Java 1.7. So, you will get a compile error in Java 1.6 or older.

Answer (score 5):

Okay so you've known how why you are getting this error.How do you get rid of it?

**Note: This is a Netbeans solution**

Right-click on the `JComboBox`, go to :

`Properties > Code >`

Under the Code tab, you'll find `Type Paramters`.

Click on the options menu to the right of it:

[image]

When the next view opens, just delete the text:

[image]

click ok and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

**-** `JComboxBox` with `Type Parameters` are **supported with the arrival of Java 7**, prior to that it **didn't** support the Type Parameter.

**See this link :**

[JComboBox Warning preventing opening the design page in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845139/jcombobox-warning-preventing-opening-the-design-page-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

You can only parameterize a generic type. [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) does not have a generic version.

**Update**

The generic version [`JComboBox<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) is available in Java 7. You probably need to upgrade your Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Even in Java 7, there is an open bug: [JDK-7067201 : Generics: BasicComboBoxRenderer](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7067201)

Answer (score 0):

Then there seems to be a bug in Eclipse (Kepler): I selected JRE 1.6, JDK 1.6, compiler compliance level 1.6 but Eclipse doesn't show any error when using JComboBox with type parameter.
Very strange.